# Is an everywhere approximately continuous function everywhere continuous? Request for a counter example

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is said to be approximately continuous at $x_0$ if there is some set $A$ which has density zero at $x_0$, such that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0,x\notin A}f(x)=f(x_0)$.

I would like to see an example of a function which is approximately continuous at all points in $\mathbb{R}$ (or, say, on some interval) but not actually continuous anywhere.

NOTE: The set $A$ is said to have density $\epsilon\in[0,1]$ at $x_0$ if $\displaystyle\lim_{\delta\to0}\dfrac{m(A\cap(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta))}{m((x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta))}=\epsilon$.

EDIT: I would in fact like even to see an explicit example of a function which is approximately continuous everywhere, and not continuous at least at one point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a sequence of pairwise disjoint closed intervals $I_n$ converging to $0$. Also arrange that the density of the union of $I_n$'s is $0$ at $0$ (for example take $|I_n|$ to be, say $1/2^n$ times the distance of $I_n$ from $0$). Now let $f$ be a function which is zero outside $I_n$'s and on each $I_n$ it is a wedge function of height one. Then $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ and is approx continuous everywhere.

Comment: Thanks Guest, this definitely does the trick at one point.  Will taking a sum of these, centered at the rationals, with the appropriate scaling factors, make the result discontinuous everywhere, or only at the rationals?

Comment: Contd.. Yes, you can get discontinuity on any countable set by summing these sort of functions. Also note that if $f$ is approximately continuous at all points then you can check that every point is a Lebesgue density point of $f$ (meaning the average values coincide with $f$) so it is Baire class one and hence must be continuous on a comeager set.

Comment: How to show that such $f$ is approx continuous at $0$?